# Fixing margin-top body tag in Yii2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii2-advanced-app

My Index had a problem in positioning the contents in `body tag` and i fixed it with below code in my `site.css`:

`margin-top: 340px;`

**and my index is ok right now!** but,

After i added this `margin-top: 340px;` in my `site.css`, other views are like this:

[image]
the body tag has a 340px from top.

So, how can i do that just for my index in yii2?

Thanks

**Code:**

```
html,
.my-navbar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 10px;
}
.tagline {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 340px;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.footer {
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #222222;
    border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
    padding: 0 0 60px;
}

.wrap > .container {
    padding: 70px 15px 20px;
}

.business-header {
    height: 400px;
    background: url('../images/header.jpg');
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .btn {
    font-size: 21px;
    padding: 14px 24px;
}

.not-set {
    color: #c55;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* add sorting icons to gridview sort links */
a.asc:after, a.desc:after {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings', fantasy;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

a.asc:after {
    content: /*"\e113"*/ "\e151";
}

a.desc:after {
    content: /*"\e114"*/ "\e152";
}

.sort-numerical a.asc:after {
    content: "\e153";
}

.sort-numerical a.desc:after {
    content: "\e154";
}

.sort-ordinal a.asc:after {
    content: "\e155";
}

.sort-ordinal a.desc:after {
    content: "\e156";
}

.grid-view th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.hint-block {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: #999;
}

.error-summary {
    color: #a94442;
    background: #fdf7f7;
    border-left: 3px solid #eed3d7;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.workspotname {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class for only the body of your index view, for example

```
<body class="margin-fix">...</bod>
```

CSS:

```
.margin-fix {
    margin-top: 340px;
}
```

If you can't add the class to the body, you could but a div as a wrapper around your content in your index view and add the class to that div.